# What happens with my iCloud data after leaving family sharing?

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

What happens with my iCloud data after leaving family sharing?

Eg I will add 50gb of data and then I will be kicked out but not all the data is on my iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Apple Support document answers your query:

- [Share an iCloud storage plan with your family](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208147)

> ### If your family stops sharing storage or you leave Family Sharing
>
> If you [leave a family](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201081) that shares an iCloud storage plan and [you're using more than 5GB of storage](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204247), you have 28 days to [buy your own plan](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201318).
>
> If you choose not to buy your own plan and the content that you’re storing in iCloud exceeds your available storage, new photos and videos won’t upload to iCloud Photos, files will no longer upload in iCloud Drive, and your iOS devices will stop backing up.

i.e., you will have 28 days of grace period to get a separate plan and keep access to your data.

Comment: What if you move from one family to another? e.g. leave family A, accept invitation to family B. I assume that all your iCloud data (drive, photos, etc) would simply follow you over to family B, but I haven't seen documentation of that anywhere. Which likely means I just haven't figured out where to look.